# Sweave compiles empty table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, knitr, sweave, miktex2.9

I have a .tex document which I want to compile using Sweave. I provide its and the .cls file's contents below. Everything works fine, except for the fact that the table of contents is empty. I am aware that one should compile the file twice for the table of contents to work properly, however Sweave seems to do this automatically. I can even see the .aux file being created and then deleted during the process.

So, everything seems to be working just fine - the .toc file is even in my directory with the proper lines and everything (I also provide its contents below)! Also, **I have compiled the same document using Overleaf, and the table of contents appeared**. I have reinstalled R, Rstudio and MikTex, but the problem persists.

I am using R 4.0.2, MikTex 2.9.6941 and pdfLaTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21

Rstudio is configured as to weave Rnw files using kintr and typeset using pdfLaTeX.

I was unsure if I should post this here or somewhere else. However the problem seems to be much more Tex related than R related.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is a known bug of RStudio: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2788#issuecomment-609072673 We are still working on it. Before it is fixed, I recommend that you use `knitr::knit2pdf()` to compile your `.Rnw` file to PDF. It calls `tinytex::latexmk()`, which will make sure to compile the `.tex` for an enough number of times (to resolve things like TOC or cross-references).

Comment: `knitr::knit2pdf()` works! I had to comment line `\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}`. Thank you very much!